# Why query performance goes down sharply when records > about 600

Tags: java, spring, oracle, mybatis

Why query performance goes down sharply when I use "INSERT ALL" query larger than about 600 records in Oracle?
Could you teach me?

I'm using Spring + Mybatis + Oracle

Following is my query.

```
    INSERT ALL
    <foreach collection="list" item="record">
      INTO tablename (
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        e,
        f,
        g,
        h,
        i,
        j,
        k,
        l,
        m,
        n,
        o
      ) VALUES (
        #{a},
        #{b},
        #{c},
        #{d},
        #{e},
        #{f},
        #{g},
        #{h},
        #{i},
        #{j},
        #{k},
        #{l},
        #{m},
        #{n},
        #{o}
      )
    </foreach>
    SELECT 1 FROM dual
```

(I changed column and variable's name. Upper query is working)

Please help me~

Comment: First thing I would try to find out, what the problem is: Run the query in your Oracle Developer (or whatever tool you are using) and see if it's slow there, too. If yes, then the problem is your query. If not, the problem is on the Java side.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I ran the upper query in Oracle Developer, and  the performance was not bad (of course I copied "INTO sentence" 600+ times without mybatis). So I retried it in JAVA "without Mybatis", and the performance was good enough. I think mybatis can be problem. Thank you! your comment was helpful.

Comment: Totally possible, hard to say without really profiling it. Activation logging would be a first step to see where it gets slow, the next one would be profiling.

Comment: Someone invented PreparedStatement to perform such a task: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html Use it, and insert only one record at a time. Use also `addBatch` to speed it up.. Your code generates huge statements, each one is diferrent, each one must be separately parsed (compiled) by the database, then the separate plan must be generated, etc. etc - this hurts the performance. Bigger SQL command - more time to parse and plan. PreparedStatement does this only once and stores in the cache, each subsequent invocation skips parsing and planning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kordirko mentioned, it's slow most probably because your usage of MyBatis insert doesn't do batching.

This is multi-row insert example [from MyBatis docs](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html):

```
<insert id="insertAuthor" useGeneratedKeys="true"
    keyProperty="id">
  insert into Author (username, password, email, bio) values
  <foreach item="item" collection="list" separator=",">
    (#{item.username}, #{item.password}, #{item.email}, #{item.bio})
  </foreach>
</insert>
```

So try to use it this way:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
    f,
    g,
    h,
    i,
    j,
    k,
    l,
    m,
    n,
    o
  ) VALUES 
  <foreach collection="list" item="record">
  (
    #{a},
    #{b},
    #{c},
    #{d},
    #{e},
    #{f},
    #{g},
    #{h},
    #{i},
    #{j},
    #{k},
    #{l},
    #{m},
    #{n},
    #{o}
  )
</foreach>
```

Answer (score -1):

The why is hard to tell. The size off the communications block, the size of your oracle process, the type of your connection, the memory configuration of the Oracle database you are using, among many others.

But another question is why you use what is essentially transaction processing for batch(bulk) related work. If hitting this wall at 600 rows is an exception, live with it. If you need this for large numbers of rows (many thousands) and often, look into batch processing techniques.

Stay away from XML and probably object-oriented techniques as well. Use tools as (s)ftp to transfer your dataset to the database server. Use external tables or sql*loader to get your data into the database. (Do not use sql*loader over a network connection, network latency will kill your performance!!). Use stored procedures for further processing.